# Magento (v.1.4.1.1) with 2 web server and 1 db setting (nginx)

Tags: nginx, loadbalancing

we are using nginx load balancing (ip 10.0.0.1) to set up magento 2 web + 1 db

> upstream web_rack {
>         #ip_hash;
>         server 10.0.0.2; #web1
>         server 10.0.0.3; #web2
>       }

in both web1 and web2, the local.xml file connects to db (ip 10.0.0.4)

however, we are not sure how to set the "base_url" (in the core_config_data table) in db.
shall we set it to 10.0.0.1?

we tried but then it seems like first time load balancer will load web1
next time if load web2, then web2 will automatically change to web1 ip.

please help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a URL for your Base_URL and not an IP address. Your Load Balancer will have the URL and then will point to each box.

domain.com -> Load Balancer (public IP + Private) -> Web1 or Web2 on PrivateIPs

Your BASE_URL should equal your domain name

Comment: actually, we are using domain name already. www.example.com has the load balancer. www1.example.com is web1 and www2.example.com is web2. but in this setting, if we set the base_url of web1 / web2 to www.example.com in local.xml, then seems won't work. please advice

Comment: just to give more details, when set base_url to www.example.com, browser returns an infinite redirect loop.

Comment: Angel, I think you are using the Load Balance feature of NGNIX and I am not to familiar with that. I would think it would have to have a unique IP address for and then it would steer your traffic to each sub ib.